# GWT-project deploy on glassfish - with Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, gwt, deployment, glassfish

I created a new project in Eclipse Helios (for Java EE): Google -> Web Application Project. Now I want to use my glassfish server, not the built-in. I have the glassfish server. I downloaded the "Glassfish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse" with the Marketplace. I unchecked the "Run built-in server" in the project's properties.

What should I do next if I want that my gwt-project, glassfish and eclipse work together? I can't find the "deploy" or something...

Because in Netbeans so much easier this: I just have to create the new gwt-project and I can choose the server I want to work with...

I need to work with Eclipse, because of the gwt-designer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to:
1. Convert your gwt project to a Dynamic Web Application project
2. Make shure to set your war folder to the one you use with gwt (default is 'war' for GWT projects and 'WebContent' for Dynamic web projects )
3. (This is the part that sucks) Make sure you compile it and any time there are changes on the client side, you have to compile again.
4. Create a new glassfish server
5. add your gwt/dynamic web project project to glassfish
6. start glassfish
7. your set!

The bad part is that you hae to compile and recompile a lot (whenever there are changes on the client side). You can use ' -localWorkers 2 ' and -draftCompile as runtime parameters so it compiles faster.
Anyway, why do you need glassfish? maby you can run it with jetty

Comment: No need to recompile! Just compile the app once, and deploy it to Glassfish. Then start *both* GlassFish (e.g. on port 8000) and the GWT code server (e.g. on port 9997). Point your browser to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997". Now you're working with GlassFish (server side) + GWT code server (client side in Development mode).

Comment: Really? that's great! I did not know that!, could you tell me how tyo start the code server?

Comment: The code server is started automatically when you run your GWT app with "Run As > Web Application". By default, this starts *two* servers: One code server, and one embedded jetty. The embedded jetty server is unnecessary in this setup, and can be disabled from the run configuration in Eclipse (in general, this is the "-noserver" option). For more on this setup, see http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s

Comment: so there is no simply, clean solution with Eclipse... :( thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To run GWT project inside EAR and using EJB try [this](http://jamies-gwt.blogspot.com/2010/03/walkthrough-integrating-gwt-with-jboss.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason for Glassfish?Usually one works with Eclipse+Jetty for development, builds a war and deploys on Tomcat/Glassfish for testing/production